# Is there an adjective for rings whose every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, terminology

(All my rings are commutative and unital.)

> **Question.** Is there an adjective for rings whose every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

Remarks:

- Every PID has this property; more generally, every Dedekind domain does.
- Every semiprimitive ring with this property is trivially a Jacobson ring.

Comment: These rings are exactly zero-dimensional rings which are not domains, and one-dimensional domains.

Comment: @Crostul, I don't get it. $\mathbb{Z}$ has Krull dimension $2$, right? $\{0\} \subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}$, for example. Or perhaps the zero ideal is omitted?

Comment: @goblin krull dimension counts the "links" between elements of the chain rather than the elements in the chain, so no, the integers are one dimensional.

Comment: @rschwieb, ah, I see. But what if the chain doesn't have links? E.g. what if our prime ideals form a poset isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @goblin the krull dimension of a ring is the supremum of such chains, so such a ring would not even have finite krull dimension, much less dimension 1 or 0

Comment: @rschwieb, can you be more precise? For starters, we're not taking suprema of chains, we're taking suprema of *lengths* of chains. So, we need to define the "length" of a chain. One way of doing this is to declare that the *length* of a chain is supremum among all cardinalities of proper subsets. This will give you $n-1$ for finite chains. If not, can you tell me, *precisely,* how you want to define "length"?

Comment: @goblin No, I am not going to explain how to read the definition of Krull dimension to you, since I know you are perfectly capable of reading it on the wiki. These imprecisions you see are the result of working on a mobile phone. Perhaps you can take this into consideration next time before writing responses with such tones. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb, a simple "not now, I don't have access to a proper computer" would suffice. I shouldn't be expected to be able to read your mind, and you should be more cautious inferring "tone" from mere unspoken writing. The Wikipedia page does not give a proper definition. By the way, I think this is *shameful.* But my ire is reserved for those who wrote the relevant page.

Comment: @Crostul nearly exact: that omits fields, which vacuously satisfy the condition

Comment: Don't criticize Wikipedia, edit Wikipedia.  Bad pages are less the result of poor authors, and more the result of potentially good authors deciding it's someone else's problem.  In any case, the Krull dimension is properly defined, on the current edit of Wikipedia, as the supremum of the lengths of the chains of primes $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_n$, where by "length" we mean simply $n$.  The supremum here is taken in $[0,\infty]$.  In other words, a ring is said to have Krull dimension $\infty$ exactly when there exist chains of arbitrary (finite) length.

Comment: In particular, $\mathbb{Z}$ has Krull dimension $1$.  The primes do not have to be "adjacent"—your example of a ring with prime spectrum isomorphic as a poset to $\mathbb{R}$ still has arbitrarily long chains, e.g. $0<1<\cdots < n$.

Comment: Note, also, that Wikipedia explicitly defines a chain of primes to be finite.  So any paranoia about infinite chains is misguided.  But note that a ring $R$ with an infinite chain also has finite chains of arbitrary length, so $\dim{R}=\infty$.  Some mathematicians are concerned with distinguishing between different types of infinite dimension, which might require talking about the cardinality of infinite chains, but such things are not part of the standard definition.

Comment: @goblin No mind reading is necessary when the topic appears in every commutative algebra text and all over the web. Perhaps 'tone' is the wrong word to describe this unnecessary tax on my comment writing. Anyhow, I'm sure you will consult the literature first in the future. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen these rings discussed, but never a never with a name attached.

The reason is probably because this class of rings is a disjoint union of the following two classes of rings which do not need complicated names and which have rather divergent properties compared to each other:

1. Rings of Krull dimension 0
2. Domains of Krull dimension 1